# iOS Storyboard segmented control jumps when clicked on

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a storyboard with an imageview, a segmented control and a textview. After appearing I make some adjustments depending on the device screen size:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"didAp");
    CGSize mainFrameSize=_mainView.frame.size;

    [_imageSpace setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, mainFrameSize.width, mainFrameSize.height*4/5)];
    [_metadadataControl setFrame:CGRectMake(0, _imageSpace.frame.size.height, mainFrameSize.width, 30)];
    [_metadataTextView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, _imageSpace.frame.size.height+_metadadataControl.frame.size.height, mainFrameSize.width, mainFrameSize.height-(_imageSpace.frame.size.height+_metadadataControl.frame.size.height))];


}
```

When the app launched everything looks like it should, but if I click the segmented control it jumps some points down. The above method is just called once before I clicked the control and I don't have any other setFrame method calls. It seems like it just loads the storyboard again.
Thank you for your help

Comment: This is probably a layout constraint problem. Either turn off auto layout, or do your adjustments using constraints, rather than setting frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rdelmar was right. It was an issue with constraints contradicting my frame settings. Switched to doing everything with auto layout and constraints afterwards.